# Riemann Geometry & Triangle Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Given a non-specific manifold with some topology what, if any, relationship could be called analogous to the regular Euclidean triangular-inequality for some non-specific geodesic. (Note, I am not sure this question is well-formed so if you have an idea about what you think I might mean to say, please feel free to share.)

Comment: What's wrong with a triangle inequality for general metric spaces?

Comment: Well I'm not actually sure there is anything wrong with it. Perhaps you can enlighten me?

Comment: You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space): Keep in mind that every connected Riemannian manifold is also a metric space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I think that's pretty much an answer.

Comment: Agreed. For some reason I was thinking it 'should' be more esoteric.